# MongoDb: Pipeline inside lookup error: Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, lookup, mongoose-populate

I have these three models:

1. `Institution` model:

```js
const InstitutionSchema = new Schema({
  current_students: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "users",
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = Institution = mongoose.model("institutions", InstitutionSchema);
```

which has array of references to `User` model in `current_students` field.

2. `User` model:

```js
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  profile: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "profiles",
  },
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

which has references to `Profile` model in `profile` field.

3. `Profile` model:

```js
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  videoURL: {
    type: String,
  },
});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model("profiles", ProfileSchema);
```

I am trying to get the list of profiles for users of an institution where `Profile.videoURL` is not `null` or `undefined`. This is what I have tried:

```js
Institution.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "current_students",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "current_student",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$current_student",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "profiles",
      localField: "current_student.profile",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "current_student_profile",
    },
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          videoURL: { $nin: [undefined, null] },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

However, I keep getting this error because of the last pipeline that executes the `$match` operation.

```
Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong. You cannot pass `pipeline` like that. Have a look at the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#restrictions) syntax. Also if you want to learn more about aggregations, I would suggest you to take up this [Aggregation course](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M121/about) offered by MongoDB themselves. It free for all.

Try this query:

```js
db.institutions.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "current_students",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "current_student",
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$current_student",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "profiles",
            localField: "current_student.profile",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "current_student_profile",
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$current_student_profile" },
    {
        $match: {
            "current_student_profile.videoURL": { $nin: [undefined, null] },
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:26 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb49a6b2dcb17e8b152b2"),
    "name" : "Institute 1",
    "current_students" : [
        ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152b8"),
        ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152b9")
    ],
    "current_student" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152b8"),
        "name" : "Dheemanth Bhat",
        "profile" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b5")
    },
    "current_student_profile" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b5"),
        "videoURL" : "http://abc1@xyz.com"
    }
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:26 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb49a6b2dcb17e8b152b3"),
    "name" : "Institute 2",
    "current_students" : [
        ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152ba")
    ],
    "current_student" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152ba"),
        "name" : "Alex Rider",
        "profile" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b7")
    },
    "current_student_profile" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b7"),
        "videoURL" : "http://abc3@xyz.com"
    }
}
```

Test data:

`users` collection:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:19:07 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152b8"),
    "name" : "Dheemanth Bhat",
    "profile" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b5")
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:19:07 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152b9"),
    "name" : "Ahmed Ghrib",
    "profile" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b6")
},

/* 3 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:19:07 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152ba"),
    "name" : "Alex Rider",
    "profile" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b7")
}
```

`profiles` collection:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:49 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b5"),
    "videoURL" : "http://abc1@xyz.com"
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:49 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b6")
},

/* 3 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:49 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb4b16b2dcb17e8b152b7"),
    "videoURL" : "http://abc3@xyz.com"
}
```

`institutions` collection

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:26 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb49a6b2dcb17e8b152b2"),
    "name" : "Institute 1",
    "current_students" : [
        ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152b8"),
        ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152b9")
    ]
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/13/2021, 6:18:26 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604cb49a6b2dcb17e8b152b3"),
    "name" : "Institute 2",
    "current_students" : [
        ObjectId("604cb4c36b2dcb17e8b152ba")
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Must be this:

```
Institution.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "current_students",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "current_student",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$current_student",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "profiles",
      localField: "current_student.profile",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "current_student_profile",
    }
   },
   {
     $match: {
       videoURL: { $nin: [undefined, null] },
     },
   }
]);
```

NB, this look like a "one-to-one" transformation from a relational RDBMS design. Usually its not the best approach to convert each **table** to a **collection**, typically the collections should have a different design.

Comment: This returns an empty array. I think it makes sense since videoURL is a field in Profile model and not in Institution Model. So as you have written it, it checks Institution.videoURL and not Profile.videoURL so it's always undefined and the returned result is an empty array.